# Can Immutable.is() take in any Immutable type?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is

I tried to compare 2 OrderedMaps and the Immutable.is function did not work.

Can it only compare Maps and Lists?

What a good way to compare deep 2 OrderedMaps?

```
    let example: Immutable.OrderedMap = Immutable.OrderedMap({
        'a': Immutable.Map({
            rate: 1.3411,
            key: 1000
        }),
        'c': Immutable.Map({
            rate: 1.3412,
            key: 1001
        }),
        'b': Immutable.Map({
            rate: 1.3412,
            key: 1002
        }),
        'd': Immutable.Map({
            rate: 1.3410,
            key: 1003
        })
    });

    let expectedResult: Immutable.OrderedMap = example;

    //adds a field to each immutable map in example
    example = modifyFunction(example);

    expect( Immutable.is(example, expectedResult) ).to.be.true;


function modifyFunction(example: Immutable.OrderedMap): Immutable.OrderedMap {


    example.forEach((item, index) => {
        item = item.set('rank', index + 1);
    });

    return example;
}
```

It keeps on returning true. I need it to be false.

Comment: [`OrderedMap#equals`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/equals) claims to use `Immutable.is` for its implementation, so I don't see why it wouldn't work. Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If you modify `example`, it will no longer be equal to `expectedResult`. `false` is the correct output.

Comment: It never returned false for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `modifyFunction` doesn't actually modify `example`. Any time you modify a data structure in ImmutableJS, it returns a new object, so `forEach` can't be used to modify an `OrderedMap`. You're looking for [`map`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/map).

```
function modifyFunction(example: Immutable.OrderedMap): Immutable.OrderedMap {
  return example.map((value, key) => {
    return value.set('rank', key + 1);
  });
}
```

So therefore, yes `Immutable.is` can take any immutable type, but you have to use the correct functions when modifying an object in order to see a change in value.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a field to the inner `Immutable.Map` instances by replacing the entire (inner) instance with one which has one field extra. **However**, that doesn't replace the reference in `example`, which is why strict equality still applies.

Consider the following:

```
var x = { z: 5 }
var y = x;

var modifyFunction = x => {
  x.z = 7; // an inner value has been modified
  return x;
};

var x = modifyFunction(x); // but it's still the same reference.

console.log(y === x); // true
console.log(y.z); // 7
```

vs

```
var modifyFunction = x => {
  var clone = {...x}; // completely new instance!
  clone.z = 7; // clone !== x
  return clone;
}
```

So unless `modifyFunction` actually returns a different instance (for example, if you were to add an entirely new entry to the `OrderedMap`), strict equality would still be true.

In order to safely modify the inner entries, make sure to use **[ImmutableJS's OrderedMap methods for modification](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap)**, I think that you're looking for `updateIn()`.

Comment: ImmutableJS structures always return a different instance when they are modified. (That's how they stay immutable). I think their `modifyFunction` isn't modifying the map.

Comment: @4castle Not when you replace the instance silently with `=`, you need to use ImmutableJS's modification methods for the magic to work. Specifically speaking, he's using `.forEach` to iterate the map, which is explicitly used for side effects, and thus unsuitable for modifying the map.